# In GeoDNS, Is it possible to have multiple A record for one US state

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns-zone, amazon-route53, geodns

I am trying to setup GeoDNs and was wondering if I can add multiple server IPs to one US state to loadbalance it.

I have 4 servers in total. 2 server will serve New York
And the other 2 serve California

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when setting up a Geolocation routing policy you can set [multiple values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-geo.html#rrsets-values-geo-value) for all record types (except CNAME), that includes multiple `A` records for multiple IP-addresses

Comment: Thanks for the info, In the route53 what is the difference between adding A records and creating traffic routing policy